# Successful SQL Injection despite PHP Magic Quotes

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I have always read that Magic Quotes do not stop SQL Injections at all but I am not able to understand why not! As an example, let's say we have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
  WHERE email='$x';
```

Now, if the user input makes `$x=' OR 1=1 --`, the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
  WHERE email='\' OR 1=1 --';
```

The backslash will be added by Magic Quotes with no damage done whatsoever!

Is there a way that I am not seeing where the user can bypass the Magic Quote insertions here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The trick is usually to pass a binary value so that the backslash would become a part of valid multibyte character. Here is a [blog post](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) about it.

Comment: I always had the impression that SQL injection was a more serious issue possibly affecting almost all newbie attempts at a script. I still can't believe that magic quotes make you absolutely safe unless you have used a multi-byte charset.